# iOS Data Protection and secure files

Tags: ios, encryption, data-protection

I'm building an app where I need to store data in an encrypted format. I've enabled `Data Protection` under `Capabilities` and added the `completeFileProtectionUntilFirstUserAuthentication` options when writing data to disk. (I need to access it from background fetch)

Everything works fine, but when I download the app container from Xcode I can see the data in clear text (plist).

Is this as it should be since I've opened the app after I unlocked my phone? Is there any way to validate that the data actually is encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to realistically validate this since everything is encrypted on disk when it's on the actual device (as long as the device has a device passcode set). They use layers of encryption keys starting at the processor and memory chip level and working up to file and part-of-file level.

Downloading an app bundle to your Mac computer from Xcode isn't the same thing as running an app bundle on an iOS device.

`NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` is the default security setting as of iOS 7, so there's no reason to set it explicitly.

> This is the
> default class for all third-party app data not otherwise assigned to a Data
> Protection class.

More info from Apple's white paper (page 16): https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf